# Heroku Deployment Errors - Node with Create-React-App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, create-react-app

Create-React-App is not working after deployment to Heroku. I get the index.html file served and test-elements showing up from html, but the react app (that's attached to another div in html) doesn't work, and gives errors as shown below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  
main.ca3192ef.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'   
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

("Unexpected token" - pointing to html's first "<" character when clicked in the browser [image]console)

[image]

Comment: can you share package.json here?
another question, are you serve your react app through node server (express)?

Comment: @Mohammednaji , package.json screenshot is above; both client and server folders have their own index.js, client holds the create-react-app, server has the starting index.js, and the index.js in root just loads the one in server directory(I added it in case it's mandatory to have index.js on the cloud)

Comment: @Mohammednaji, Yes, the react app is served through node server; here's the code for deployment                                                                                                                      ``` if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   app.use(express.static('../client/build'));
   app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      var reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '../');
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(reqPath, "client", "build", "index.html"))  //__dirname is the current directory
   })
}

Comment: @DavitG have you tried using [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) ? It can simplify the deploy process a bit.

Comment: @NKiD, I have not tried build packs as I wasn't planning to get errors like this, but my index.js is being served after deploy(as you can see the 'test div' on the screenshot, which means some small fix could resolve the entire issue). I'll definitely take a look at it ! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. 
The issue was that the static assets (including the React App) were just not being served - the directory should be given from the perspective of the root directory

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you share what you changed?

Comment: the static assets path was incorrect, here's a reference https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html